# How can i solve that slowdown loading this static page?

Tags: php, web, hosting, web-hosting, vps

I have a very simple static php page which i found it takes between 300 to 500ms to load when i tested it on USA and Germany using pingdom and web speed testing websites. i tested this page on a localhost and i found that it takes in average around 20ms to load. So i'm wondering if there is a problem with my webhosting and if so then do you suggest any other shared webhosting that can provide better performance?

I'm using Hostgator Cloud Plan
Php 7.1
Im using Cloudflare CDN

This is the page

```
https://bonvivo.de/amazon/
```

And this is the page source

```
https://jsfiddle.net/arabtornado/tb16d7xf/1/
```

and here is a test result

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2cO5.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to other shared hosting company (A2Hosting) Amsterdam datacenter, Turbo shared plan. Here is a test for the same page (Page delivered from the hosting server not from the cdn) snag.gy/2EwLBo.jpg

TTFB from when tested from frankfurt is 38-80ms